# long ago used as a noun in a sentence

Tags: word-usage

I found a sentence on Google. This is

> "People of long ago wore a watch on a chain tucked in their vest pockets.".

Can we use "long ago" as noun?

Comment: The locution **of long ago** is idiomatic.  Time-phrases often have both nominal and adverbial uses, "The cities of tomorrow", "they're arriving tomorrow".

Answer (score 1):

The locution of long ago is idiomatic. Time-phrases often have both nominal and adverbial uses, "The cities of tomorrow", "they're arriving tomorrow". – Tᴚoɯɐuo